# \displaystyle remains ineffective, how to use it?

Tags: displaystyle

I am trying to use the "\displaystyle" to write equations. but it is not being effective. the parenthesis, when used around a fraction, remain to be small rather than adjusting the size accordingly. What is the problem? Is there some package i require for this?

Comment: I suspect you are looking for `\biggl(...\biggr)`. `\displaystyle` makes a different job.

Comment: Or `\left( stuff \right)` for auto-adjusting.

Comment: Choices include `\big`, `\bigg`, `\Big`, and `\Bigg`, in addition to the `\left(...\right)` nomenclature

Comment: Ok thanks guys. Got it. I saw a video that said it could be done in this way. Thanks

Comment: Hey Phelype, does your method require any package?

Comment: Video where? A lot of the videos online about LaTeX are not good quality

Comment: In the YouTube. I guess you are right. I looked at some videos as I it is my first time in LaTex

Comment: @SamapanBhadury No, none of the methods mentioned here require any package. `\left` and `\right` are TeX primitives, and `\big`, `\bigr`, `\bigl`, etc. are defined in terms of `\left`, `\right`, and other primitives.

Comment: you should almost never need `\displaystyle` (certain environments such as `equation` use displaystyle automatically, but it is rather rare to need to explicitly switch to display style.

Comment: One example would be in an array, which switches to \textstyle.